# Given N containers find the blob

Tags: c#, .net, azure

We have a setup where a given uuid tagged blob could be in one of N containers or none.

What is the best way to check all containers in parallel returning the blob if found or reporting blob doesn't exist?

Our container names are dates and there won't be more than five at any given time there will only be one blob.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CloudBlob.FetchAttributes()` which does a HEAD on the blob and will throw an exception if it fails. (essentially testing if exists)

So just create your container & blob handles in a loop, test if exists, and return if true.

```
public static class BlobExtensions
{
    public static bool Exists(this CloudBlob blob)
    {
        try
        {
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            return true;
        }
        catch (StorageClientException e)
        {
            if (e.ErrorCode == StorageErrorCode.ResourceNotFound)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish to look in each of the containers in parallel without an existence check round trip.

Comment: It should report the blob doesn't exist if it couldn't be loaded from any of the containers.

Comment: then stick the above code in a Parallel.Foreach() and break out of the loop if you find what you're looking for. You'll have to check each container individually, as the checking for blob existence is just checking that you get a HTTP 200 OK for a Web Request.